# Concurrently using WinRT and Win32 in a C++ application

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, winui-3

We are wanting to build an application that can also be deployed as a Service (with the UI switched off) – and the direction we are WANTING to take is:

1. Build the core application using Windows APIs i.e. Win32 APIs (for multi-threading, communication, disk-IO, timer routines – including interfacing with device for network interfaces, sleep/wakeup, and other life-cycle events)
2. Build the UI components ‘only’ using WinUI 3 (for all Visual UI including Printing, and User interaction)

We are expecting the shelf-life of our architecture to be several years from today for current and future evolutions of Windows.

From what we have read and understood so far, our interpretation is that WinRT (which is the gateway to WinUI 3) provides interfaces on top of Windows API (Win32) and does not conflict with being concurrently used in the same application. Is this true? we were trying to make use of WinRT just as the UI component where we already have our project in Win32 structure as the core. Also, we would like to understand if there is anything we should be particularly careful about in this regard.

We came across this concept where we can host XAML contents on the Win32 window's HWND, by which we can use both WinRT and Win32[WinRT elements as UI in win32's code structure], [Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp)
But this was for the UWP XAML hosting, traditional UWP APIs that reference the WinUI 3.0 NuGet package[Which comes under winrt::Windows Namespace]

But I wanted the "WinUI in Desktop" [classic Win32 app that references the WinUI 3.0 NuGet package, comes under winrt::Microsoft namespace] as the UI component, which is, I wanted to make use of the APIs under the winrt::Microsoft namespace.

I came across Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Hosting but I was not able to find classes like DesktopWindowXamlSource to achieve XAML hosting.

It would be of great help if you could help us to get a detailed understanding of these subjects. And also a detailed understanding of what exactly a "WinUI in UWP" app or a "WinUI in Desktop" app means.

Mainly when we use UIElement under winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml as a UI component what difference will that make from using winrt::Windows::UI::Xaml's UIElement as the UIComponent? Or if I'm taking it in the wrong direction

Thank You

Comment: To sum up: WinRT => new general Windows API. Windows.UI.Xaml => UWP, Microsoft.UI.Xaml => WinUI. For the future, you want to forget about UWP completely. More info in this excellent article https://www.thomasclaudiushuber.com/2021/02/05/what-is-actually-the-universal-windows-platform-and-what-is-winui-msix-and-project-reunion/ (should be written by Microsoft)

Comment: There are too many questions here. I will answer only the first one: Yes, you can use classic Win32 and C++/WinRT together.

Comment: @RaymondChen thank you for your response, can we use classic win32 and winui together? Can we use Microsoft.UI.Xaml elements in win32 application? just like as we can do it for Windows.UI.Xaml [ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/host-standard-control-with-xaml-islands-cpp ]

Comment: Only one question per question please.

Comment: @RaymondChen Apologies. Can we use elements from Microsoft.UI.XAML in win32 applications?

Comment: Yes. You use XAML Islands. Example: [Building Windows Terminal with WinUI](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/building-windows-terminal-with-winui/). [Here's their repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/Terminal).